# Authorization roles Spring-boot Oauth2 ~ Restful API

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

i'm needing help with this problem...
i can't secure my controllers in my security configuration files. but i can do it in my controller using

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

but this is really annoying, i want to do it from my security conf. files

this is my WebSecurityconfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
//@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false)
//@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
//@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService cuds;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(cuds)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/test").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/usuarios/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

and this is my Oauth2Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Oauth2Configuration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    // Logout
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                    .and()
                    //Session management
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    //URI's to verify
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/logout").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/usuarios/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
        }
    }
```

i've tried to use authority and roles, but nothings works. some idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: perhaps a problem of ordering? what if you put 
`.antMatchers("/usuarios/**").hasRole("ADMIN")`
before
`.antMatchers("/**").authenticated()`

Comment: Man, i love u!! haha, was a problem with the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to Yannic Klem i got the answer, was a problem with the order

First on my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` i set my authentication on "usuarios"

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/usuarios").authenticated();
    }
```

after that in my `Oauth2Configuration` set my authorizarion with my rol.

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // Logout
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                //Session management
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                //URI's to verify
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/logout").permitAll()                    
                .antMatchers("/usuarios/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
    }
```

and now all works pretty fine. thank you all!